# Codename One: How to Change Picker PopUp Design?

Tags: codenameone

In my app, I have added a date & time picker which are working wonderful. Of course, the standard design does not fit into my apps design, but I can't figure out how to design the PopUps when clicking the pickers. I can change their UIID, but this does not affect the PopUps Display.PICKER_TYPE_DATE or Display.PICKER_TYPE_DATE.

Could you give me an instruction and example here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can customize the look of the picker in the simulator this won't impact the look on the device. On iOS/Andorid/Windows picker is rendered natively so you will see a style that isn't customizable as it's platform dependent.

If you are looking for a heavily customizable approach I suggest looking at our [suggested alternatives to ComboBox](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-dont-use-combobox.html).